# How to split() a string before date

Tags: python, regex, split

I have a string of text which contains a date in the second half in the format `%d.%m.%y %H:%M` plus `|`. The first half contains the name of the user, which can vary in length, can contain numbers, can have multiple trailing blank spaces and also multiple white spaces within parts of the name. For example:

```
john   smith    23    21.01.1994 02:23|
mr    magoo    30.04.05 23:37|
    Mr bing bong    29.01.10 20:53|
```

How could I safely split the string into two?

This

```
name_date = "john   smith    23    21.01.1994 02:23"
name = name_date.split("    ")[0].encode('utf-8').strip()
date = name_date.split("    ")[1].encode('utf-8').strip()
date = date.split(" |")[0]
```

works most of the time but still leave out the case of 4 spaces () within the name.

Comment: what output do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a task ideally suited for regular expressions:

```
import re

dtpattern = re.compile(r'(?<=\s)\d{2}\.\d{2}\.(?:\d{2}|\d{4})\s+\d{2}:\d{2}(?=|)')
date = dtpattern.search(name_date).group()
```

This matches a pattern of digits (each group of digits either 2 or 4 digits long) with the appropriate separators in between; the look-behind and look-ahead patterns ensure that the match is limited to those dates with whitespace before it and a pipe character after.

```
>>> import re
>>> samples = '''\
... john   smith    23    21.01.1994 02:23|
... mr    magoo    30.04.05 23:37|
...     Mr bing bong    29.01.10 20:53|
... '''.splitlines()
>>> dtpattern = re.compile(r'(?<=\s)\d{2}\.\d{2}\.(?:\d{2}|\d{4})\s+\d{2}:\d{2}(?=|)')
>>> for line in samples:
...     print dtpattern.search(line).group()
... 
21.01.1994 02:23
30.04.05 23:37
29.01.10 20:53
```

If you needed the name *as well*, group everything before the whitespace, as well as the date pattern:

```
dtpattern = re.compile(r'(.*?)\s+(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.(?:\d{2}|\d{4})\s+\d{2}:\d{2})|')
name, date = dtpattern.search(name_date).groups()

>>> dtpattern = re.compile(r'(.*?)\s+(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.(?:\d{2}|\d{4})\s+\d{2}:\d{2})|')
>>> for line in samples:
...     name, date = dtpattern.search(line).groups()
...     print name
...     print date
... 
john   smith    23
21.01.1994 02:23
mr    magoo
30.04.05 23:37
    Mr bing bong
29.01.10 20:53
```

Comment: Why not just `\d+` or `\d{2,}` instead of the longer `(?:\d{2}|\d{4})`. Obviously this is boarder (accept more than just 2 or 4 digits), but will still work especially consider how strict the rest of the regex is

Comment: @skamazin: because the year is either 2 or 4 digits; you could use `\d{2,4}` there indeed, but then it's just more correct to match either 2 or 4 digits.

Comment: I suppose I value more concise regex as oppose to strict ones. Just an opinion though! Your's is perfectly valid as is. Is that any better way to match exactly 2 or 4 digits? The non-capture group is quite long and `\d{2,4}` also captures 3 digits. Any ideas?

Comment: @skamazin: there is no other option to match either 2 or 4 digits, but not 3.

Answer (score 0):

If it's always date at last 2 items you can try this:

```
name_date = "john   smith    23    21.01.1994 02:23"
name = " ".join(filter(None, name_date.split(" ")[:-2]))
date = " ".join(filter(None, name_date.split(" ")[-2:]))
print name, date
```

Output:

```
john smith 23 21.01.1994 02:23
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `split` with no parameter and then you can easy get any of the data you need or even put back in to one normalized string, separated by either spaces or commas.

```
>>> name_date = name_date.split()
['john', 'smith', '23', '21.01.1994', '02:23|']
>>> name_date[3]
'21.01.1994'
>>> ', '.join(name_date)
'john, smith, 23, 21.01.1994, 02:23|'
>>> ' '.join(name_date)
'john smith 23 21.01.1994 02:23|'
```